# How to overload operators that dont change object's fields outside a class?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

For example I need to overload == operator. How can I do it outside a class . (Without prototype).

Comment: This question is best answered with a good C++ book. Perhaps you should have a look at the [C++ recommended book list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/).

Comment: I've read books, but this seems to be impossible for me.
This operator need an acces to private fields. But this cant be done outside a class.

Comment: @aleshka-batman it can, with the adequate [`friend` declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend).

Comment: @Quentin without friend keyword.

Comment: @aleshka-batman You can't.  If you need access to the private data then it needs to be a member function or a friend function.

Comment: Only a class and its friends can access its private members. So, no, you can't access private members without the means to access private members. Why do you need to perform a task while banning the required tools?

Comment: @NathanOliver i've found a solution using the link you gave me.



class X {
  X& operator+=(const X& rhs)
  {
    // actual addition of rhs to *this
    return *this;
  }
};
inline X operator+(X lhs, const X& rhs)
{
  lhs += rhs;
  return lhs;
}


operator(+) is defined outside the class,but it calls overloaded operator (+=)inside the class

Comment: @aleshka-batman That `operator+` relies on `operator+=` being public.